# orderly transition vs. peaceful transition

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "an orderly transition" as the equivalent of "a peaceful transition (of authority)". Am I on the right track?

"Peaceful" might sound sarcastic after the riot at Capitol. But "an orderly transition" appears to convey, or be forced to convey, the essense of being peaceful in the process of transfer, or in the promise of this lost president.

I am not sure.

> Congress affirms Biden’s win
> Hours after pro-Trump mob storms U.S. Capitol, House and Senate reconvene >to confirm president-elect’s victory
> Final stamp made on Biden’s election after riot at Capitol
> The counting of the electoral college votes brought an end to a historically turbulent post-election period as President Trump pledged “an **orderly transition**.”

> Source:  [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/)

Comment: _Orderly_ means 'with everyone keeping order (behaving correctly)'.

Comment: That would be featured with being peaceful, generally speaking.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Comment: Yes, it would, but 'orderly doesn't _mean_ 'peaceful', as Astralbee says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Orderly means *organised*, or *well-arranged*.
- Peaceful means *calm*, *undisturbed by strife, turmoil, or disagreement*. It can also mean *quiet*.

They can be mutually exclusive - for example, if a large crowd filed into an arena slowly and obeyed all the guidelines on queueing etc then you might say they are *orderly*, but if they were making a very loud noise then you might not say they were 'peaceful' because of the noise alone.

There are situations where the meanings can blur a little - for example, in schools, children are often required to be quiet and making a noise could be considered disruptive, and therefore *disorderly*.

In the context of your example, an "orderly transition" sounds like one that follows the proper process. Not to express a political opinion, but it could be suggested by some that this word was chosen specifically so as not to exclude a protest while the transition takes place.